# Model binding with a JSON array/object of non-sequential indices

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Referring the Phil Haack's [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/), I can bind to a view model without using sequential indicies, for example:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

My `Foo/Edit.cshtml`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Bars.Index" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="Bars[123].Baz" value="Chips" />

<input type="hidden" name="Bars.Index" value="caliente" />
<input type="text" name="Bars[caliente].Baz" value="Salsa" />
```

`Bars` is populated correctly when the form is submitted via an normal HTTP Post request. However if I serialize the form to JSON, i.e. using [`serializeJSON`](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) to serialize the form and then submit via AJAX, the JSON payload was not correct:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Amount": 26.4,
    "Bars": {
         "123": {
             "Id": 1,
             "Baz": "Chips"
         },
         "caliente": {
             "Id": 2,
             "Baz": "Salsa"
         },
         "Index": "caliente" <-- Extra property in the JSON object
    }
}
```

which cannot be bound to the `Bars` property in my `FooViewModel` (`Bars` becomes null). Any ideas how I can bind a collection property when using JSON objects with non-sequential indices?

Comment: Try `$('form').serialize();` or `.serializeArray()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is not possible as it does not `.serialize()` returns a params string and `.serializeArray()` does not serialize nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a

```
Dictionary<string, Bar>
```

for your Bars param, it should be able to understand the serialized JSON you're obtaining.